# standard error of columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r

I know that by using `sapply`, one can find the `mean`, `median` or `sd` of columns of a data frame. I have a data frame with many columns and I am wondering how I can use `sapply` to determine the standard error (se) of each columns in the data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you calculate standard error by dividing sd by n.

```
data=matrix(1:20,4,5)
mf <- function(x){sd(data[,x])/sqrt(length(data[,x]))}
sapply(1:length(data[1,]),mf)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in a data frame as you say, then this is an alternative that is actually a bit more efficient.

```
sapply(df,function(x)sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))
```

A data frame is a list of lists (e.g., each column is a list). So passing `df` to `sapply(...)` will cause each column of `df` to be passed to the function. This is more efficient than passing an index and extracting the lists in the function.

Comparing results:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20),4,5))

mf <- function(x){sd(df[,x])/sqrt(length(df[,x]))}
sapply(1:length(df[1,]),mf)
# [1] 0.25025825 0.77221460 0.54097317 0.38468680 0.07733118

sapply(df,function(x)sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))
#         X1         X2         X3         X4         X5 
# 0.25025825 0.77221460 0.54097317 0.38468680 0.07733118
```